# Flask request is returning 404 not found

Tags: python, flask-restful

I'm using Flast Restplus for my API and I'm working on Swagger documentation.
I split the API in multiple namespaces and I'm having a hard time to get the proper url:

**activity.py:**

```
activities_api = Namespace("activities", description="activities of the company", path='/')

class Activity(Resource):
    def get(self):
        pass
    @activities_api.doc(params={'name': 'activity name'})
    def post(self):
        pass 
    @activities_api.doc(params={'ID': 'activity ID'})       
    def delete(self, activity_id):   
        pass          
    @activities_api.doc(params={'ID': 'ID de l\'activité'})  
    def put(self, activity_id):
       pass   

 activities_api.add_resource(Activity, '/activities', endpoint='/')
```

**api.py:**

```
from activities import activities_api
app = Flask( __name__)
api = Api(app, prefix='/v1/', default = None, title='API', version='1.0', catch_all_404s=True)
api.add_namespace(activities_api)
```

In the home page I get the following paths:

> ```
> PUT
> /v1/activities
> POST
> /v1/activities
> DELETE
> /v1/activities
> GET
> /v1/activities
> ```

When I make a curl GET to /v1/activities I get:

```
"GET /v1/activities / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Should I use `blueprints` with `Namespaces` ? 
This is the structure of my API:

```
app.py
__init__.py
activities.py
```

simple as this, but the routes are wrong.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

There is only a minor mistake I think.

It is this line:

```
api = Api(app, prefix='/v1/', default = None, title='API', version='1.0', catch_all_404s=True)
```

Instead of saying `prefix='/v1/'`, try `prefix='/v1'`. Since when you add the extra `/` to the end the url will point to `/v1//activities`.

Comment: I tried that and I still get not found :( the data is not available on `/v1//activities` either

Comment: So, or I am totally misinterpreting your question or the code you posted above has no mistake in it. What I can say is that you saying `endpoint='/'` is not really doing anything but I don't think it is what causes the problem. You should certainly remove the `/` from `/v1/`.